# How tensorflow use back propagation in training the model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am a beginner with tensorflow and I want to implement MLP and train it based on the back propagation algorithm but when I read tutorials I found that it uses optmizers like “Stochastic Gradient Descent” and called it back propagation without implementing the algorithm phases. How is this back propagation?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you use these optimizers by first defining the loss function and then invoking optimizer's `.optimize` on it:

```
loss = some_loss(predicted_outputs, true_outputs)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Now, executing `sess.run(train_op)` will make a step in the direction of the gradients of weights to minimize loss.

Comment: ok , if i talk about backpropagation as 2 phases feedforward the model with data and backpropgation to adjust the weights ,, thats mean "tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()" is the backpropgation  pahse to adjust weights to mnimize the cost ,, is that true ?

Comment: In a sense yes, as the "forward pass" is realized by the `loss` tensor. But you need to keep in mind that execution is lazy in TF and running `sess.run(train_op)` will force tensorflow to execute `loss` first.

Comment: okeey but what if i change the optmizer to another one like adamoptmizer is that still backpropagation or not as i know  bp is based on GradientDescent so i use it in training with bp.

Comment: All the optimizers in TF are based on the idea of Gradient Descent and use backpropagation. The `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` is implementing a raw SGD.

Comment: iam sorry but if it is, what is major difference between optmizers if all of them  based on the idea of Gradient Descent and use backpropagation ?

Comment: They all calculate the gradients, but use them to different extent. For example, Momentum stores previous gradients and take them into account when moving (it has some "momentum" in the movement), Adam stores a sum of squares of some previous gradients to normalize, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help：

> In [18], two approaches for back-propagating gradients through a
>   computational graph are described. The first, which the authors refer
>   to as symbol-to-number differentiation, re- ceives a set of input
>   values and then computes the numerical values of the gradients at
>   those input values. It does so by explicitly traversing the graph
>   first in the forward order (forward-propagation) to compute the cost,
>   then in reverse order (back-propagation) to compute the gradients via
>   the chain rule. Another approach, more relevant to TensorFlow, is what
>   [18] calls symbol-to-symbol derivatives and [8] terms automatic
>   gradient computation. In this case, gradients are not computed by an
>   explicit implementation of the back- propagation algorithm. Rather,
>   special nodes are added to the computational graph that calculate the
>   gradient of each operation and thus ultimately the chain rule. To
>   perform back- propagation, these nodes must then simply be executed
>   like any other nodes by the graph evaluation engine. As such, this
>   approach does not produce the desired derivatives as a numeric value,
>   but only as a symbolic handle to compute those values.

Reference: http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.0117